# Firestore date range Query - Same day search

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a timestamp field named createdAt in Firestore Database. I'm using Firebase SDK for Web

In the UI I am showing **Start Date** and **End Date**

```
.where('createdAt', '>=', startDate)
.where('createdAt', '<=', endDate)
```

The query works as expected, but when I have the same date on both fields I don't get the results on that date and instead I get an empty result.

Is there a way to fetch a single date results while selecting same date in a range search?

Example:

```
Start Dte       End Date         Result
10/03/2020     12/03/2020  -> returns 11/03/2020 items
11/03/2020     11/03/2020  -> returns empty
```

Comment: How exactly are you storing those dates?  What is `startDate` and `endDate`?  Please edit the question provide more precise data about what your queries and data.

Comment: The dates are stored as Timestamp. The date format I am using in the query is not the problem as it works, im just worried how **>=** works

Comment: Actually, the date formis **is** kind of a problem.  Timestamps are stored without local timezone data.  They are always represented in UTC.  If your query timestamps are also not converted to UTC, exactly representing the day boundaries you intend, you could miss data simply because of bad assumptions about timezone.  Without seeing more specific examples, we can't tell if this is actually the case, though.